# Can I not use a variable in with Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a variable I pull from a form that I need to tie in with a matching display name to retrieve an existing samAccountName.

```
 If (Get-ADUser -Filter { (displayName -eq $user) -AND ($Returner -eq "Yes")} ) { 
    $Check = Get-ADUser -Filter{displayName -eq $user} -Properties SamAccountName
    $sam = $check.SamAccountName
    $sam
    }
```

As soon as I have the -AND ($Returner.....) part in there the check fails to execute.

I need that check in there as that is what is passed from the Cherwell form to flag that a user is a returner and then I am going to pull in the current samAccountName for that person.

Can someone assist on how I should be using a check of a parameter in with the Get-ADUser command.

Many thanks

S.

Comment: you are using the `scriptblock` format for your `-Filter` ... but that parameter requires a **_string_**. the "brilliant persons" who designed the AD module allow the scriptblock format [and use it for many examples], but it is not reliable for complex filters. you likely will need to switch to a string similar to >>> `-Filter "(displayName -eq $user) -AND ($Returner -eq 'Yes')"` <<<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would perform the same `Get-ADUser` command twice..

You can do this like below:

```
$adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$user'" -Properties DisplayName, SamAccountName
$sam = if (($adUser) -and $Returner -eq "Yes" ) { $adUser.SamAccountName }
$sam
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, that does look way neater - I will put it into dev and see how it hangs together.

Comment: is this $sam = if (($adUser)  checking for Null?  so basically if $adUser has a value and $returner = Yes then create the $sam variable?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$Returner` inside of the `-filter` of `get-aduser`. If I understand correctly, this is a variable created by a form.

You should check for `$Returner` inside of the if statement:

```
If ( (Get-ADUser -Filter { displayName -eq $user}) -AND ($Returner -eq "Yes")) { 
    $Check = Get-ADUser -Filter{displayName -eq $user} -Properties SamAccountName
    $sam = $check.SamAccountName
    $sam
}
```